# how to install the AMD driver on Ubuntu 23.04 ? ( with the SLEEPING monstrosity AMD 7900 xtx )

Tags: games, steam, gpu-driver, amdgpu, 23.04

in the past i own a 5700 + nitro something for STEAM gaming, and i am used ONLY the X.ORG driver. in some cases some games SLOWS down to 20 (!!!) FPS and i am not pleased. ( euro truck 2 in ultrawide ( 2 x full HD ) with 9x the traffic AI ) today, i get this monstrosity GPU, the 7900 XTX OC.
the problem with the FPS is the same with the RX5700, and i am NOT EXPECT this .
i think the problem focused on X.ORG driver, i think i should install the drivers from the [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-rx-7000-series/amd-radeon-rx-7900-series/amd-radeon-rx-7900xtx) site.
NOT work as should be, a LOT of errors appears when i try out infos on [this links](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=7900%20xt) .
rumors says if i am installs the AMD driver, the STEAM cannot run the PROTON magic trick anymore ... i am measured the GPU usage by percentage, and when the game runs on aproxx 50 FPS ths GPU is only 20 % usage, the CPU is around 30-50 % usage . like the card, and the CPU both is SLEEPING on the job ...
so my question is here :
HOW I CAN install the AMD driver into my Ubuntu 23.04 system ?

[image: my system infos R here]